# How to execute a file on /sdcard?

Tags: android

I'm trying to run sqlite3 on my rooted Nexus 4. I've gotten as far as pushing the executable to /sdcard but I cannot execute it. I'm running stock Android 4.3, rooted with SuperSU 1.45.

The file looks like this:

```
-rw-rw-r-- root     sdcard_rw    36860 2013-09-30 17:29 sqlite3
```

So far:

- `chmod 777 sqlite3` does nothing
- `File.setExecutable()` returns false (but `File.exists()` returns true).

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Did you try explicitly call "chmod +x database.sqlite"?

Comment: chmod +x doesn't work on Android. I get "bad mode".  BTW I did get it to work but copying sqlite3 to /data/local. It just work work in /sdcard.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

SD cards are usually formatted as FAT32 and mounted with all files unexecutable. SD card directory on Nexus 4 is a simulated one, but still the system prevents any file in it to be marked as executable. You need to move your file outside of your SD card to mark it as executable.

Comment: Looks like /data/local/tmp works on most Android installs (not FireTV though :( ..)

Comment: @nmr From /init.rc: "For security reasons, /data/local/tmp should always be empty. Do not place files or directories in /data/local/tmp." /data/local appears to be a safe place to store files though.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question.
But I want to suggest another work around for this problem by creating disk `.img` file in sdcard then mount it on /data/

Well, I know it was quite redundant, but at the very least it could be used as workaround if your internal disk was low on space.

Here, some instructions in case needed.

1. `adb shell` to your device,
2. go to `/sdcard` (mouting point may vary on each device)
3. `dd if=/dev/zero of=<your-new>.img bs=1M count=0 seek=2048`. This creates a new image file called `<your-new>.img` change the seek value to the size you want (e.g 2048 = 2GB). If dd not available, try to install `busybox` first, then from `dd` change into `busybox dd`
4. Format `<yout-new>.img`, in my case I used ext2. eg. `mke2fs -F ubuntunew.img`
5. Mount `<your-new>.img` to `/data`. eg. `mount -o loop /sdcard/<your-new>.img /data/<your-mount-point>`. If `mount` command not available use `busybox`.

Ok. That's all

References:

https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2743108
https://linuxonandroid.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/74683-how-to-i-give-linux-more-space

Answer (score 3):

> chmod 777 sqlite3 does nothing...
>
> chmod +x doesn't work... I get "bad mode".

The "Bad Mode" is from `a+x`, `+x`, etc. Remember, its octal. Try:

```
chmod 0777 sqlite3
```

And Yuichi is probably correct - `/mnt/sdcard` is likely mounted with `noexec`.

Comment: Operation not permitetd